# Best way to set a channel for a logger in a class in C++

Tags: c++, logging, poco

I am developing a C++ class that uses the Poco library in order to log some messages.

I have split the class in 2 files `MyClass.h` (for declaration) and `MyClass.cpp` (for definition).

This is the `.h` file content:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

class MyClass {
protected:
  static Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::ConsoleChannel> packetChannel;
  static Poco::Logger& logger;
}
```

I have made the logger and the channel static to make them common for all objects.

And this is the `.cpp` file content:

```
Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::ConsoleChannel> GenericSensor::packetChannel = new Poco::ConsoleChannel;
Poco::Logger& GenericSensor::logger = Poco::Logger::get("SensorsChannel");
Poco::Logger& GenericSensor::logger.setChannel(packetChannel);
```

The first 2 lines are ok. But the third line is generating an error,
saying: `expected a ';'`

I know that the error is most probably because in the `.cpp` file we can have only definitions.

And I know that I can set the logger's channel in the constructor, but in that way, it will be set each time I have a new object of type `MyClass`.

Is there a method to set it just one time?

**Edit 1:**
I have one **suggestion**.

I propose to define a new method in the `.cpp` file. It takes the channel as a parameter, initializes a new logger, then sets the channel to the new logger, and finally, it returns the new logger. As follows:

```
Poco::Logger& getLoggerWithAChannel(Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::ConsoleChannel> channelToSet) {
    Poco::Logger& logger = Poco::Logger::get("SensorsChannel");
    logger.setChannel(channelToSet);
    return logger;
}
```

And then we can define the channel, the logger, and set the logger's channel in 2 lines as follows:

```
Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::ConsoleChannel> MyClass::packetChannel = new ConsoleChannel;
Logger& MyClass::logger = getLoggerWithAChannel(packetChannel);
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you think this line is supposed to do:

```
Poco::Logger& GenericSensor::logger.setChannel(packetChannel);
```

It's neither a variable declaration nor a function declaration (no datatype on the parameter passed).

Edits after the discussion with the OP. He's trying to execute code, but you can't do that this way. This is bad code.

What he needs to do is create a static method that executes this code (without the weird non-variable declaration part) and call it from the constructor. The static method should keep track of whether it's already been done and only do it if necessary.

Comment: In this line, I am trying to set the single channel that I have "packetChannel", to the single logger that I have "logger".

Comment: Do you see why it's bad code? First, you can't have executable code outside of a method, unless your initializing a global variable. That's not a variable declaration/definition. But you have a data type hanging out in front with no variable name or anything like that. It needs to go in a method and get rid of the datatype part.

Comment: Yes I know it is a bad code, but what I am actually trying to do is to find an alternative, that can define the logger and set the channel to it only one time. That is why I avoided to do that in the constructor, because the set will be repeated each time a new object is created.

Comment: Make a static method that keeps track if it's already been done, and call it from the constructor.